# Infragistics toolbar, how to show PopupMenu checked state?

Tags: toolbar, infragistics

I have a toolbar managed by UltraToolbarsManager with a StateButton and a PopupMenu tool on it.

Both these controls have a Checked setting.
When I set Checked = true on both controls the StateButton changes appearance but the PopupMenu does not. As I am using the PopupMenu as a glorified multistate checkbox I would like them to behave similarly

i.e. if any of the StateButtons under the PopupMenu are checked then the PopupMenu should display checked as if it were a StateButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the PopupMenu display as a state button by setting the DropDownArrowStyle of the PopupMenuTool to SegmentedStateButton.  The following links in the NetAdvantage for Windows Forms help explain this further:

http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR2.0/?page=Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinToolbars.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.PopupToolBase~DropDownArrowStyle.html

http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR2.0/?page=Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinToolbars.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.DropDownArrowStyle.html